# Vectorize these nested for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I usually can figure out how to vectorize with a little thought, but despite reading through a bunch of StackOverflow q&a's, I'm still stumped!
I want to replace these nested for loops with a suitable apply function, but if there is some obvious different approach to the whole problem that I've missed, feel free to tell me so!

Think of this example in the context of a test where the first row is the key and each subsequent row is a students' answers. As output, I want an array with a 1 for every correct answer and a 0 for every incorrect answer. The for loops work, but are VERY slow when you scale up to thousands of rows and columns.

Here's my reproducible example, and thanks in advance for any help!

```
   #build sample data
    dat <- array(dim=c(9,6))
    for (n in 1:9){
       dat[n,1:6] <- c(paste("ID00",n,sep=""),
           sample(c("A","B","C","D"), size=5, replace=TRUE))}
    dat[3,4]<-NA
    key<-c("key","A","B","B","C","D")
    dat <- rbind(key,dat)

>dat
[,1]    [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
"key"   "A"  "B"  "B"  "C"  "D" 
"ID001" "B"  "A"  "D"  "B"  "C" 
"ID002" "C"  "C"  "C"  "B"  "B" 
"ID003" "A"  "C"  NA   "D"  "D" 
"ID004" "D"  "B"  "D"  "A"  "A" 
"ID005" "A"  "C"  "A"  "C"  "A" 
"ID006" "D"  "D"  "B"  "B"  "A" 
"ID007" "B"  "D"  "A"  "D"  "A" 
"ID008" "D"  "D"  "B"  "D"  "A" 
"ID009" "D"  "C"  "B"  "D"  "D" 

    #score file
    dat2 <- array(dim=c(9,5))
    for (row in 2:10){
      for (column in 2:6){
        if (is.na(dat[row,column])){
          p <- NA
        }else if (dat[row,column]==dat[1,column]){
          p <- 1
        }else p <- 0
        dat2[row-1,column-1]<-p
      }
    }
> dat2
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    1    0   NA    0    1
[4,]    0    1    0    0    0
[5,]    1    0    0    1    0
[6,]    0    0    1    0    0
[7,]    0    0    0    0    0
[8,]    0    0    1    0    0
[9,]    0    0    1    0    1
```

Comment: I strongly believe that the solution to this is to completely rethink your data structures....I'll try to concoct an example.

Comment: I got side-tracked, and you got other answers....never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a seed for reproducibility:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- array(dim=c(9,6))
for (n in 1:9){
   dat[n,1:6] <- c(paste("ID00",n,sep=""),
       sample(c("A","B","C","D"), size=5, replace=TRUE))}
dat[3,4]<-NA
key<-c("key","A","B","B","C","D")
dat <- rbind(key,dat)
```

This will do the job:

```
key <- rep(dat[1, -1], each = nrow(dat) - 1L)  ## expand "key" row
dummy <- (dat[-1, -1] == key) + 0L  ## vectorized / element-wise "=="
```

Basically we want a vectorized `"=="`. But we need first expand `dat[1,-1]` to the same dimension of `dat[-1,-1]`. Finally the `+ 0L` coerce `TRUE / FALSE` matrix to `1 / 0` matrix.

```
#  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#    0    1    0    0    0
#    0    0    0    1    0
#    1    0   NA    0    1
#    0    0    0    0    1
#    0    0    0    0    0
#    0    0    1    0    0
#    0    0    1    0    1
#    0    0    0    1    0
#    0    0    0    1    0
```

---

I haven't check with Gregor's benchmark script yet. But here is mine.

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- matrix(sample(LETTERS[4], 1000 * 1000, TRUE), 1000)
key <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 1000, TRUE)
microbenchmark(rep(key, each = 1000) == dat, t(t(dat) == key))

#Unit: milliseconds
#                         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq
# rep(key, each = 1000) == dat 32.16888 34.01138 42.61639 35.57526 40.27944
#             t(t(dat) == key) 50.93348 52.96008 63.74475 56.04706 60.38750
#       max neval cld
#  81.96044   100  a 
# 106.54916   100   b
```

The only difference between my method and Gregor's is the `rep(, each)` expansion v.s. `rep_len` expansion. Both expansion costs the same amount of memory and after expansion, `"=="` is done in column-wise fashion. I predict extra overhead will be caused by two `t()`, which the benchmarking result seems to justify. Hopefully the result is not platform dependent.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same as Zheyuan's answer (relying on vectorized `==` then coercing back to numeric), I just transpose the matrix first instead of expanding the key.

Since matrices are stored/operated on by columns rather than rows, if the key is a column and each student is also a column vector recycling will work out just fine.

Using `set.seed(1)` before generating the data...

```
key = dat[1, -1]
tdat = t(dat[-1, -1])
t((tdat == key) + 0L)
 # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 #    0    1    0    0    0
 #    0    0    0    1    0
 #    1    0   NA    0    1
 #    0    0    0    0    1
 #    0    0    0    0    0
 #    0    0    1    0    0
 #    0    0    1    0    1
 #    0    0    0    1    0
 #    0    0    0    1    0
```

If you instead change the first column to row names instead they can be easily preserved with no risk of marking students IDs as incorrect because they aren't `'key'`. This makes summarizing things at the end nicer as well:

```
row.names(dat) = dat[, 1]
dat = dat[, -1]
key = dat[1, ]   

tdat = t(dat[-1, ])
result = t((tdat == key) + 0)
result
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# ID001    0    1    0    0    0
# ID002    0    0    0    1    0
# ID003    1    0   NA    0    1
# ID004    0    0    0    0    1
# ID005    0    0    0    0    0
# ID006    0    0    1    0    0
# ID007    0    0    1    0    1
# ID008    0    0    0    1    0
# ID009    0    0    0    1    0

rowSums(result)
# ID001 ID002 ID003 ID004 ID005 ID006 ID007 ID008 ID009 
#     1     1    NA     1     0     1     2     1     1
```

---

Simplifying the inputs and running a benchmark on moderately sized data, both are quite quick. The double transpose is a bit faster.

```
gregor = function(key, dat) {
    t(t(dat) == key)
}

zheyuan = function(key, dat) {
    dat == rep(key, each = nrow(dat))
}

library(microbenchmark)
nr = 10000
nc = 1000
key = sample(1:10, nc, replace = T)
dat = matrix(sample(1:10, nr * nc, replace = T), nrow = nr)

print(microbenchmark(gregor(key, dat), zheyuan(key, dat)), signif = 4)
# Unit: milliseconds
#               expr   min    lq     mean median    uq   max neval cld
#   gregor(key, dat) 104.5 113.2 135.5970  128.2 144.5 336.2   100  a 
#  zheyuan(key, dat) 196.0 202.8 215.7822  207.0 224.9 394.4   100   b

identical(gregor(key, dat), zheyan(key, dat))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Yes, I realized we're both using recycling just in different places.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I knew I was missing something obvious!!

Comment: I'm curious what it will be on larger data - of course transpose introduces overhead but so does creating a `key` matrix of the same dimensions as the original.

Comment: Hmm, that's good to know. I am surprised then because in a simplified benchmark the double transpose seems faster

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in one line without `for` or `apply`, try something like

```
dat2 <- matrix(as.numeric(dat==rep(dat[1,],each=nrow(dat))),nrow=nrow(dat))[-1,-1]
```